# Как передать параметры в функции которую я вешаю на слушатель событий. JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу, что бы  при уборки фокуса эта строка становилась неактивной и затем буду отправлять пост запрос на бэк. для этого мне необходимо в функцию `changedInfo` передать параметр какую строчку я делаю неактивной, но не вызывать эту функцию

```
   Object.keys(workerString).map((item) =>{
      // console.log(workerString[item])
      workerString[item].disabled = false
      workerString[item].addEventListener("focus", changeInfo)
      workerString[item].addEventListener("focusout",changedInfo)
    })



  const changeInfo =  () => {
    console.log("test")
  }

  const changedInfo = (row) => {
    Object.keys(row).map((item) =>{
      // console.log(workerString[item])
      row[item].disabled = true
    })
  }
```

Comment: В слушатели передаются стандартные параметры события. Передать кастомные данные не получится(Без каких либо изворотов). Детализируйте свой вопрос, указав все детали и желаемое поведение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать замыкание что бы передать параметр:

```
Object.keys(workerString).map((item) =>{
  // console.log(workerString[item])
  workerString[item].disabled = false;
  workerString[item].addEventListener("focus", changeInfo);
  workerString[item].addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
    changedInfo(event.target);
  });
});
```

Comment: Но event и так передается. Что поменялось? И event это стандартные данные события, а не кастомные данные...

Comment: @SwaD Я хотел просто передать строчку в функцию, не вызывая эту функцию.

Comment: @AntonBuketov Ответ и то что у вас, ничем не отличается. Меняете в своем примере `Object.keys(row)` на `Object.keys(row.target)` и будет то же самое... Но смотрите сами )

Comment: @SwaD Не думал в эту сторону

Comment: На удивление я так же не подумал в сторону мысли @SwaD, и так же согласен с AntonBuketov.